# events on 2 div at the same time on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, z-index, mouseover

I'd like to know if there's a way to trigger events on 2 div at the same time on mouse over in javascript/jquery if they are both at the same location but on different z-index ?

example :

[like in this example http://imageshack.com/a/img849/8684/k8jn.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img849/8684/k8jn.jpg)

Comment: How about a third element (the double area) and trigger both events from there?

Comment: see there: http://jsfiddle.net/9f4mr/

Comment: Fiddle for demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a4CqH/1

Comment: @axel.michel unfortunatly not an option in my case

Comment: @A. Wolff wow, I didn't know about passThrough, I'm going to play with it

Comment: @BrennanSei `passThrough` is just a namespace, not an event. The imporatnt function is `document.elementFromPoint()`.

Comment: @A. Wolff oh sorry for my misunderstanding, I just had a closer look and read the informations about that function and it seems to be a very interesting ones. however in your example when I click in the inbetween area it only trigger the top ones, does that mean that this function doesn't work if z-index are involved ?

Comment: Check this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/9f4mr/23/

Comment: @BrennanSei there is a bug when wrapping it inside iframe and scrolling body, coming from elementFromPoint() method. See, here it works: http://jsfiddle.net/tjWb9/show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to use `elementFromPoint()` method:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjWb9/show)  {be aware of bug if using wrapped iframe and scolling body's iframe}

```
$divs = $("#one, #two").on('click.passThrough', function (e, ee) {
   var $el = $(this).hide();
  try {
    if (!ee) $("#msg").empty();
    $("<div/>").append($el.text()).appendTo($("#msg"));      
    ee = ee || {
      pageX: e.pageX,
      pageY: e.pageY
    };
    var next = document.elementFromPoint(ee.pageX, ee.pageY);
    next = (next.nodeType == 3) ? next.parentNode : next //Opera
    $(next).trigger('click.passThrough', ee);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("click.passThrough failed: " + err.message);
  } finally {
    $el.show();
  }
    alert('div cliked: #' + this.id);
});
```

Original Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416567/1414562

Answer (score 1):

```
Listen "mousemove" event in wrapper div,
use event object pageX and PageY to find Cursor above both div or not.
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/9f4mr/23/